# Using regexp to find variable group of letters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing a basic algorithm scripting challenge on FCC and I want to return `true` if a string in a first element of an array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array, or `false` otherwise.

I've written some code for this. However I can't seem to pass one test:

```
mutation(["hello", "Hello"])
```

I've tried removing the global flag and have tried using constructor notation and literal notation based on recommendations from the FCC community, but to no avail.

This is the code:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  let patt = new RegExp("[arr.1]", "i");
  return patt.test(arr[0]);

}

mutation(["hello", "Hello"])
```

The function is supposed to return `true` instead it returns `false`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you want to match with `[arr.1]` pattern? It matches a single char, `a`, `r`, `.` or `1`. Nothing close to `hello` or `Hello`.

Comment: You don't need a regex for this: `[...second].every(x => first.includes(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new RegExp("[arr.1]", "i")` uses `[arr.1]` (literally) as the regular expression, which is why it doesn't work.

I wouldn't use a regular expression for this, it's simpler to do it directly. For instance:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  const lc = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  return [...arr[1].toLowerCase()].every(ch => lc.includes(ch));
}
```

...or to make searching the string not be a linear search:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  const chars = new Set([...arr[0].toLowerCase()]);
  return [...arr[1].toLowerCase()].every(ch => chars.has(ch));
}
```

...but if you **have** to use regex, you could generate an array with all the permutations of `arr[1]` (`["Hello", "oHell", "loHel", ...]`) (perhaps using [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)) then create your regular expression using beginning/ending anchors (`^`, `$`) and alternations (`|`) of all the permutations:

```
let permutations = /*...use the linked answers to create permutations...*/;
let patt = new RegExp("^(?:" + permutations.join("|") + ")$", "i");
```

If `arr[1]` may contain characters that are special in regular expressions, you'll need to escape them (perhaps using [one of the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)):

```
let patt = new RegExp("^(?:" + permutations.map(escapeRegExp).join("|") + ")$", "i");
```

(Again: There is no built-in `escapeRegExp`, see the answers to the question linked above for how to create one.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. (For some reason FCC lets it pass most of the tests, which is why I didnt catch that error). But when I used your code, it passes the test even if it only matches with one letter. I want it to match all the letters.

Comment: @raeign - Doh! Of course it does. :-) (The RegExp version. The others are right.) I wouldn't use RegExp for this, I'd use one of the other solutions. But hmmmm.....

Comment: wow, i see now why no one wants to use regex for this question. Thanks for your help!